# SQL append "-large" to every second row where column name is "clean_name"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Is this possible?

I want to append the string "-large" to every second row within my `products` table, where the column is `clean_name`

Comment: How do want to do it? With SQL or from PHP?

Comment: Sorry, within MySQL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [modulo operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) (`%`) on an `id` column

```
update products
set clean_name = concat(clean_name, '-large')
where id % 2 = 0
```

Comment: Can you explain the `id % 2 = 0`?

Comment: what if some rows have been deleted ?

Comment: it divides `id` with `2` and returns the rest of the devision. You can select every row ehere no rest is left (`0`).